# I have a pfx file can I create a certificate witha private key from that

Tags: certificate, pfx

I am a little confused on all this certificate stuff.  I want to create a certificate with a private key (exportable if possible).  How do I do that.  I already have a .pfx file.  Can I use that to create a certificate with that private key?

Comment: `openssl pkcs12 -info -in path_to_file.pfx` shows you all information about pfx file.

Comment: do I have to download openssl?  Or is it native with windows products?

Comment: openssl is open-source tool. You can download it from  http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on what you intend to do with this PFX certificate?

Answer (score 1):

A pfx file normally contains a private and a public key. That is why this file is normally password protected.

Depending on your operating system you can create new certificates with openssl or the certificate manager in the system options in windows.

Here is a screen of a actual wildcard certificate:

[image: wildcard cert]

Comment: is it possible to generate a certificate from that?  Sorry for the dumb questions, I am just confused on the subject... Security was never one of my strong suits

Comment: That depends on the key constrains. If this pfx file contains a root certificate so yes, if not no ;)

Comment: E.g. import the certificate in your certificate store and have a look to the key usage fields.